# Esp32 fails to read MH-Z19C sensor

Tags: sensors, esp32

I'm trying to read CO2 data from a MH-Z19C sensor with an ESP32 board but I'm not getting anything. The error code from the library is 2 indicating a timeout (no data received).

Did I get the wiring wrong?
I wonder if the sensor is fried ?

Library: MH-Z19 by Jonathan Dempsey

Connections:

- MH-Z19C RX to TX2 (17)
- MH-Z19C TX to RX2 (16)
- MH-Z19C VIN to Power Supply 5V
- MH-Z19C GND to Power Supply 3V

Code:

```cpp
#include <SoftwareSerial.h>
#include <MHZ19.h>
#include <Wire.h>


// pin for uart reading
#define RX_PIN 16  // Rx pin which the MHZ19 Tx pin is attached to.
#define TX_PIN 17 // Tx pin which the MHZ19 Rx pin is attached to.

MHZ19 myMHZ19;
SoftwareSerial mySerial(RX_PIN, TX_PIN);

void setup() {
  Serial.begin(9600);

  // Start Co2 sensor
  mySerial.begin(9600);                               // (Uno example) device to MH-Z19 serial start
  myMHZ19.begin(mySerial);                                // *Serial(Stream) refence must be passed to library begin().
  myMHZ19.autoCalibration();                              // Turn auto calibration ON (OFF autoCalibration(false))
}

void loop() {
  // Wait a few seconds between measurements.
  delay(5000);

  int CO2;
  // Request CO2 (as ppm)
  CO2 = myMHZ19.getCO2();
  Serial.println(String(CO2) + " ppm");

  if (myMHZ19.errorCode != RESULT_OK) {
    Serial.print("Failed to receive CO2 value: ");
    Serial.println(myMHZ19.errorCode);
  }
}
```

[image: backwards]
[image: wiring]
[image: esp32]
[image: power supply]
[image: circuit]

Comment: It is too difficult to follow your wiring in those pictures. A schematic diagram would be much better. You have mentioned a 3.3v and a 5v supply.  Do these share a common ground?

Comment: It is unclear how the GND are connected between the boards. It will be better to have a schematic than those pictures.

Comment: ok edited. note that the board is powered with USB while the sensor is powered by a power supply module.

Comment: I would connect the esp gnd to the z19c gnd.

Comment: Do you mean I should power the sensor with esp's GND/VIN? The issue is that the sensor needs 5v and the board only delivers 3.3V if I'm correct

Comment: It means connect PIN1 of ESP32S(GND) to pin2 of of Z19C(GND), basic 101 electronics.

Comment: Ok I connected GND of ESP32 to Power Supply GND to which PIN2 of Z19C is also connected. Is that correct? I'm still not receiving any data.

Answer (score 1):

This is not a Winsen Mh-z19 sensor (or any clone following it's specs) so you won't be able to read data using a mhz19 library.
Most probably it's a HC8 sensor and someone would have to rewrite library to get data from it.
Here are specs: https://pcus.ru/download/hc8.pdf and some more info:
https://spezifisch.codeberg.page/posts/2022-08-23/co2-sensor-reverse-engineering/

Comment: how do you know it's not mh-z19?